# iTextSharp RAM (memory) overflow

Tags: c#, pdf, шаблоны, itextsharp

Здравствуйте!

Я генерирую PDF документ на основе шаблонов. Документ состоит из нескольких страниц (может быть более 5000). При создании 500-й страницы я получаю переполнение памяти. Какие-нибудь идеи? Спасибо за советы!

```
public static void CreateBankBlank2012Year(string pdfTemplatePath, string directoryOutPdf, string nameOutPdf, AnnualReportsFilterParameters filterParametrs, string serverPath)
{
    // Get details salary
    IEnumerable<SalayDetailsForPdf> dataSalaryDetails = (IEnumerable<SalayDetailsForPdf>) GetSalaryData(filterParametrs);

    String fontPath = Path.Combine(serverPath + "\\Fonts", "STSONG.ttf");
    Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 8);

    using (Document document = new Document())
    {
        using (PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(
            document, new FileStream(directoryOutPdf + nameOutPdf, FileMode.Create))
        )
        {
            document.Open();

            foreach (var data in dataSalaryDetails)                    
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplatePath + @"\EmptyTemplateBankBlank_2012.pdf");
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                    {
                        stamper.AcroFields.AddSubstitutionFont(font.BaseFont);
                        AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
                                                                                                                            form.SetField("t1_address1", data.Address1);

                        form.SetField("t1_name", data.NameHieroglyphic);

                        // Other field ...

                        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                    }
                    reader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());

                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, 1));
                }
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: @Maximus, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Answer (score 2):

Вытеснять созданные 499 страницы на диск, после десятой итерации смержить документы в один 5000 страничный.

Comment: @Mike PDF, задавший вопрос пользователь, конечно, получит уведомление на email, но, скорее всего, этот вопрос уже не стоит два с половиной года спустя.

Comment: @Etki лучше поздно, чем никогда.